# Unable to update features in tables without FID: How to use gid field as the FID column with ogr/gdal python?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-python-binding

I'm trying to update a PostGIS table using the `SetField()` method in python. The table is imported from a shapefile  with `pgsql2shp` so it has a `gid` field, which can be used as FID or primary key.

However, when executing `SetField()`, I get an error saying:

```
Error 1: Unable to update features in tables without a recognised FID column.
```

I tried different things. The only thing that allows updating is to externally add and populate a new column called `ogc_fid`. Even adding a 'fid' column won't do.

Is there a way to tell ogr/gdal (as of gdal2.1.3) in the python code itself that an *existing* field such as `gid` is the FID column?

Comment: Why don't you add primary key constraint to your existing `gid` field?

Comment: @user30184, the test table was imported using `shp2pgsql` directly. I didn't want to change the table for a specific client package (unless I have to).

Comment: Every spatial table should really have a primary key. Could you try to run shp2psql with -I flag? That should force gid to primary key. If gid is already a PK but GDAL does not recognize it there may be a bug.