# Cannot "Move Feature" in QGIS for PostGIS layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I cannot seem to `Move Feature` for PostGIS layers in QGIS 3 (2.99 43a9bc1) after I enabled editing as shown below.

[image]

Even though I can add features with the `Add` button, the `Move Feature` button is greyed out.

Does anyone know what might be the cause or how to fix it?

--EDIT--

Regarding the table, I do have the privileges as I am the owner of the db, and I just verified that I can create features in it. I also created a field called `ogc_field` because of prior issue with updating the table in question. [Unable to update features in tables without FID: How to use gid field as the FID column with ogr/gdal python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/250357/34474) .

`ogc_fid | integer              | not null default nextval('cfl.match_opl_prmatch_ex_pl62__p5_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass) | plain    |`

I don't know if this is sufficient for QGIS.

Comment: from my experience using the move feature will not work with a postgis table. save it as a geoJSON and it should work

Comment: move works, you need the correct privileges...

Comment: @DPSSpatial ive tried it as a superuser and the tool was grayed out. but maybe you are correct

Comment: Primary Key is always a factor when editing PostGIS data in QGIS... @ziggy I always look for that first...

Answer (score 7):

Your user is lacking the `UPDATE` privilege on the layer.

PS: after granting it, you would need to re-open the project to see the changes.

Answer (score 4):

Does your dataset have a primary key assigned? Even if its just an arbitrary OBJECTID, you need to have that to do any editing in QGIS.

Comment: This solved the issue for me!